# С++. Удаление двумерных динамических массивов

Tags: c++, указатели, память, динамические-массивы

Я пока плохо разбираюсь в указателях и массивах, это мои первые шаги.
Я гуглил свою проблему, но не смог понять, чем плох мой код, что не нравится Visual Studio.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

inline void del_ptr_array(char** arr, unsigned int size) // здесь ошибка
// удаляет элементы массива указателей char**
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        delete[] arr[i];
    delete[] arr;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int size = 1;
    char** words = new char* [size];
    words[0] = (char*)"words";

    del_ptr_array(words, size);

    return 0;
}
```

Функция del_ptr_array должна удалять двумерные массивы типа char**, это мне нужно для проекта. Но при вызове функции постоянно возникает исключение:

```
//
// delete_scalar.cpp
//
//      Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
//
// Defines the scalar operator delete.
//
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <vcruntime_new.h>
#include <vcstartup_internal.h>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// delete() Fallback Ordering
//
// +-------------+
// |delete_scalar<----+-----------------------+
// +--^----------+    |                       |
//    |               |                       |
// +--+---------+  +--+---------------+  +----+----------------+
// |delete_array|  |delete_scalar_size|  |delete_scalar_nothrow|
// +--^----^----+  +------------------+  +---------------------+
//    |    |
//    |    +-------------------+
//    |                        |
// +--+--------------+  +------+-------------+
// |delete_array_size|  |delete_array_nothrow|
// +-----------------+  +--------------------+

_CRT_SECURITYCRITICAL_ATTRIBUTE
void __CRTDECL operator delete(void* const block) noexcept
{
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    _free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK); // здесь вызывается точка останова
    #else
    free(block);
    #endif
}
```

Чем может быть вызвано исключение? Как заставить это все работать? ))
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите, вот здесь вы выделяете память для `words`.

```
char** words = new char* [size];
```

Все нормально, и `delete[] words` оправданно и полно смысла — освободить и вернуть в пул памяти то, что было выделено.

Далее вы делаете

```
words[0] = (char*)"words";
```

Т.е. ваш `words[0]` указывает на память, которая через `new` **НЕ** выделалась. Так что удаление такой памяти в

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    delete[] arr[i];
```

приводит к неопределенному поведению (читай — проблемам). Что не менее неприятно, все прочие `words[i]` никак не инициализировались вообще, и указывают на какие-то случайные места в памяти. Но эти случайные места вы тоже пытаетесь освободить! Итог — у вас сразу `size` проблем...

Удалять через `delete` можно только то, что выделялось через `new`!

Что делать? Зависит от того, что вы делаете.

Если вы используете указатели на строковые литералы или на иные, не выделенные через `new` области памяти — просто не освобождайте их.

Если хотите хранить в них что-то с выделением памяти и последующим освобождением — вы должны выделить им память (или хотя бы обнулить эти указатели).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь - больше не появляются исключения